# how to loop through select with custom attributes in jQuery

Tags: jquery, each, attr

I have a select dropdown with custom attributes that looks like this:

```
<select id="myselect">
<option value="1" custattr="first">First One</option>
<option value="2" custattr="second">Second One</option>
<option value="3" custattr="third">Third One</option>
</select>
```

And I have a value or values that I want to test against to see if they are not present in the `custattr` of each option.

I have tried variations of the following:

```
    jQuery('#myselect option').attr('custattr').each(function(){
        if (myvalue != jQuery(this).attr('custattr').val()) {
        //do something
       }
    });
```

but I get errors such as:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'each' of undefined

How can I loop through to test against each `custattr` value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to iterate it like below.

```
jQuery('#myselect option').each(function(){
    if (myvalue != jQuery(this).attr('custattr')) {
    //do something
});
```

`.attr()` would return a `string`. Hence it wouldn't have a function called `each` in its proto chain.

Comment: Thanks I think that is part of the answer, but when I make that change I now get an error saying `Cannot read property 'val' of undefined`

Comment: @Stephen, Just use `if(myvalue != jQuery(this).attr('custattr'))` no need for `.val()`

Comment: oh duh! Thanks! Accepted as answer as soon as they let me.

Comment: @Satpal Thanks mate. I went out after posting this one. Didn't notice that.

Answer (score 0):

If you want get property attr 'custattr'

```
//jquery 
$(document).on('change','select',function(){
    var attr= $(this).find('option:selected').attr('data-custattr');
    alert(attr)
});
//  JS 
document.querySelector('select').onchange = function(){
    var attr= this.selectedOptions[0].getAttribute('data-custattr');
    alert(attr);
};
```